# Gravity forms date based price calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm a WP newbie and am amazed so far by what it can do. I am currently using Gravity forms to charge my customers for a monthly subscription plan. However I give my users option to choose the months they want to enrol for and charge them for it as they enrol.

```
FromDate = Date entered by the user in From Date field  (in days)
ToDate = Date entered by the user in To date field  (in days)
```

So my formula for price calculation is:

```
(ToDate - FromDate)* (cost per day of my subscription)
```

However, I don't know how to implement this. Any help would deeply be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of the gravity form builder page]

Answer (score 0):

The [Gravity Forms Date Time Calculator](http://www.screencast.com/t/ya7Dd5rm0SSf) plugin will allow you do to all sorts of date-based calculations. It's available by request to [Gravity Perks](http://gravityperks.com) users.